# Show/Hide elements in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am messing around with React.js for the first time and cannot find a way to show or hide New input field on place of my label.
I messed around little bit but in the end i got stuck and deleted editItem code,This is my code so far and I dont know how to continue/Create editItem function.
Any sugestions?

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        todos: [],
    };
    handleInputValue = (event) => {
        console.log('-------handleinputvalue');
        this.setState({inputValue: event.target.value, id: uuidv4()});
    }
    addItem = () => {
        let {inputValue, todos, id} = this.state
        this.setState({todos: [...todos, {inputValue, id}]})
        console.log('Assigned id to new item',this.state)
    }
    deleteItem = (todoID) => {
        const todos = this.state.todos.filter((item => item.id !== todoID))
        this.setState({todos})
        console.log('------todoId',todoID)
    }

    editItem =(todoId) => {

    }

    render() {
        console.log('-------render');
        return (

            <div className={"App"}>
                <div className="App-header">
                    <h2>Welcome to To-Do List App</h2>
                </div>
                <input onChange={this.handleInputValue} name={''} type='text'/>
                <button onClick={() => this.addItem()} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Add</button>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.todos.map((item) => <li key={uuidv4()}>
                        <input type={'checkbox'}/>
                        <label>{item.inputValue}</label>
                        <input type={'text'} className={'hidden'}/>
                        <button onClick={() => this.deleteItem(item.id)} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Delete</button>
                        <button className={'btn btn-primary'}>Edit</button>
                    </li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: The way to show/hide something is to a) add a respective variable to your component's `state` b) write JSX that renders the element, or not: `{this.state.isVisible && <div>...</div>}` c) use `setState` as usual to change the visibility (you should also edit your question to include a clear problem statement; right now it's in danger of getting closed as "needs details or clarity")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is *conditional rendering*.

Basically, you only render a component when a condition is true. Check out the React docs, specifically [the part about inline && operators](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).

A quick example:

Using the `&&` operator to only render something when a condition is true:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShowMessage((p) => !p)}>Toggle message</button>
      // the message div will only be rendered when showMessage is true
      {showMessage && <div>This is a message!</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

using the ternary operator `condition ? a : b` to render either one thing or another:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [showFirstMessage, setShowFirstMessage] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShowFirstMessage((p) => !p)}>
        Toggle message
      </button>
      // If showFirstMessage is true, the first message will be rendered, else the second message will be rendered
      {showFirstMessage ? (
        <div>I'm the first message!</div>
      ) : (
        <div>Hi, I'm the second message</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```